# Python: Decorator + list comprehension - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension, decorator

I am trying to return a list with divided by 2 to get even numbers in the list. 
I am trying to do this with decorators but I am getting error as `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

And my code is

```py
def getEven(fnc): 
    def inner(list_of_val):
        return [ devideBy2(int(value)) for value in list_of_val ]
    return inner

@getEven
def devideBy2(num):
    return int(num)/2

list_of_num = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(devideBy2(list_of_num))
```

When I iterated through `list_of_num` Its printing each number and my thinking is like, now this each number will pass an argument to `devideBy2` function and returns the result of `num/2`

But I am ending up with `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Please help me understand where I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: `fnc(int(value))` instead of `devideBy2(int(value))`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, Thank you. Now I understood where I am doing wrong. Please add this as answer.

Comment: You are calling the function directly instead of `return [ fnc(...`

Comment: Note: having the decorator alter the signature of the function in its meaning/types isn't recommended

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ I haved added it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function you are passing inside the `inner` function instead of calling the function you are decorating. Also you are already converting passed value to `int` in `fnc`, no need to do it again in `getEven`

```
def getEven(fnc): 
    def inner(list_of_val):

        # Call fnc here instead of devideBy2
        return [ fnc(value) for value in list_of_val ]
    return inner

@getEven
def devideBy2(num):
    return int(num)/2

list_of_num = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(devideBy2(list_of_num))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this,

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> def div_by_two(func):
...   def wrapper(nums):
...     func(nums)
...     return [num // 2 for num in nums]
...   return wrapper
... 
>>>
>>> @div_by_two
... def some_func(nums):
...   print(nums)
...   return nums
... 
>>> 
>>> some_func(nums)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`HERE :`

```py
In [0]: def getEven(fnc):
    ...:     def inner(list_of_val):
    ...:         return [fnc(value) for value in list_of_val]
    ...:     return inner
    ...:
    ...: @getEven
    ...: def devideBy2(num):
    ...:     return num // 2
    ...:
    ...: list_of_num = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ...:
    ...: print(devideBy2(list_of_num))
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the list contains integer numbers separated by commas and list is iterable in this , but  you are trying to convert those iterable values (multiple integer values ) to a single value to non  iterable value, but in Python cross conversion is not supported( logically also) ,means can't convert multiple values to single value and vice-versa so that type is not available hence it shows type error,if the list was a single value and you tried to convert it to a integer it would have worked.